# How can I properly set the height of my Silverlight UserControl?

Tags: silverlight

I can't get my silverlight control to go any taller than 600.  Please see code below to reproduce this behavior.  Notice that the color bands stop at exaclty 600.  Can anyone tell me how to get this example to Show all rows in the grid?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            <asp:Silverlight ID="Xaml1" runat="server" Source="~/ClientBin/IT.xap" MinimumVersion="2.0.31005.0" Width="100%" Height="100%" />
            </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<UserControl xmlns:my1="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data" x:Class="IT.Test"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Width="400" Height="1225">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
            <RowDefinition Height="175"/>
            <RowDefinition  Height="175"/>
            <RowDefinition  Height="175"/>
            <RowDefinition  Height="175"/>
            <RowDefinition  Height="175"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="175" />
            <RowDefinition Height="175" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="Green"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="Red" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Fill="Blue" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Fill="Orange"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="4" Fill="Yellow" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="5" Fill="Black" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="6" Fill="Aqua"/>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: Your sample is incomplete. Put up the whole XAML, because I think what's stopping you is at the top of the XAML.

Comment: We usually don't answer our own questions around here ;) To answer, there's a "code" button at the top of the text box.

Comment: Thank you for fixing this Rich.  How can I delete my answer?  Can I delete my other dupe question?

Answer (score 0):

I set the Grid's background to Gray (Background="Gray") and all the row heights to 50 to see what was going on. I think that your UserControl is taller than your browser's viewport, but since it's empty the scrollbars aren't showing up. So I get a gray band at the bottom that goes all the way down to the bottom of that page.

Edit: if you want a UserControl that takes up the entire viewport, remove the Width and Height from the UserControl tag.

Comment: jcollum, thanks for your reply.  removing the width and height from the usercontrol tag does not do the trick.  Since you copied the code to your machine, can you get it to work?